# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache') with role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i work on a discord bot but i have a problem when i want to know if user who clicked on button have a role

```
if (interaction.customId === "button_one") {
            responseembed.description = `\u200b\n**${config.responses.response_1}**\n\u200b\n`

            if (interaction.user.roles.cache.has(config.lspd_role_id)) {
                const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.lspd_channel_id)
            }else if (interaction.user.roles.cache.has(config.lssd_role_id)) {
                const logchannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(config.lssd_channel_id)
            }
            
            logchannel.send({ embeds: [PriseService], ephemeral: false })
            // let invitecutie = new MessageButton()
            //     .setLabel("Invite Link")
            //     .setStyle("url")
            //     .setURL("Link")
            // let buttonRow = new MessageActionRow()
            //  .addComponent(invitecutie)
            //!If You Want Button in the Response remove // from the the Above 6 lines
            return interaction.reply({ embeds: [responseembed], ephemeral: true })//If you want to send link button add ,component: buttonRow after the ephermeral: true declaration
        }
```

but i have this error :

> if (interaction.user.roles.cache.has(config.lspd_role_id)) {
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')

Comment: `interaction.user.roles` is `undefined`. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: i want to check il user has a specific role , people who use button of my message

Comment: Ok, but `interaction.user.roles` is `undefined`. Why do you expect something different?

Comment: Is not undefined , he need to be the rôle of user who click the buttons ?

Comment: Why is undefined?

Comment: how can i have role of people who clicked on the button

Comment: Add `console.log(interaction.user.roles)` to see yourself. I don't know where it comes from, but it's `undefined`. Where do you set it?

Comment: `User`s don't have roles, only `GuildMember`s have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must access the roles from a `GuildMember` object. You can get the member with [`BaseInteraction#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/BaseInteraction?scrollTo=member)

```js
if (interaction.member.roles.cache.has(id)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`User`'s doesn't have roles in cache, only `GuildMember`'s have.

Instead of getting users' roles, you must fetch him as guildmember (member) and then search his roles in cache.

```js
const user = interaction.user
const member = interaction.guild.members.fetch({ user: user })

if (member.roles.cache.has(config.lspd_role_id)) return true
// output: true

if (user.roles.cache.has(config.lspd_role_id)) return true
// expected output: true
// output: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
```